# Search for pages via Graph API, response empty

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-page

When I send the request `search?type=page&q=test&access_token=[access_token]` to Graph API, the response is empty data. Is there a problem with the access token or is there something missing from the request URI? I also can't seem to find a comprehensive documentation of the search method, only that for places search.

This is the response I'm getting:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook made a lot of changes recently:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

> You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object
>   types:
>
> - event
> - group
> - page
> - user

Comment: So is there no current possibility to search for a page by location?

Comment: your question was about pages, not places. since places are not mentioned in the deprecation, i assume you can still search for them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/search

Comment: I am still asking about pages, the result should be an array of page IDs, but filtered by location. since I cannot search for pages anymore, is there any way to search for a place and get the pages of that place?

Comment: i don´t think so, no. thake a look at the commented link, there is no field for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :
[https://graph.facebook.com/pages/search?q=[PageName]&fields=id,name,link,location&access_token=[access_token]](https://graph.facebook.com/pages/search?q=%5BPageName%5D&fields=id,name,link,location&access_token=%5Baccess_token%5D)

it worked for me